# plotting figure from saved traces in pymc

Tags: python, plot, pickle, pymc, mcmc

I need to run MCMC different times with different parameters to check the convergence. So I decided to save the traces so that when I need to know (for comaprison purposes) what was the result of

`pymc.MCMC (iter = 10000, burn = 1000, thin = 10)`

I don't need to rerun it. (It takes a lot of time (I have to do the same for many different values of parameters)).

I found out a solution

```
m = MCMC([tau, rv], db='pickle', dbname='10000iter1000burn.pickle')
m.sample(iter = 10000, burn = 5000, thin = 10)
m.db.close()
```

So the trace is saved now in a database named **10000iter1000burn.pickle**

Now, to load teh trace, I do the following

```
db = pymc.database.pickle.load('10000iter5000burn.pickle')
```

and when I perform `print db.trace('tau')[:]` I get the same output, but when I want tp plot the figure or get other information, it fails

```
plot(db)  #error
```

**plot() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)**
but when I do plot(m) (initial case when I have run the sampler again), it works fine.

Similarly `db.tau.summary()` gives error **'Trace' object has no attribute 'summary'**
It works fine when I do `m.tau.summary()`

Same is true for `db.logp`

I am a novice in this field. Kindly correct me if there is any mistake somewhere in the syntax.
If there is some other way that I can replot the figure and get log-probability of the model without running mcmc again, I will be happy to know.

Comment: I'm guessing you've imported `*` from some library that has overwritten the `plot` function from matplotlib. Try importing `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and calling `plt.plot(db)`.

Comment: Yes you were right but I still get error message **TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just pass a database backend to the plot function. You can either pass (1) the original node/stochastic (2) a trace object (3) a dictionary of pymc nodes/stochastics or (4) raw output.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were using the pymc.Matplot.plot function. You need to access the traces from the loaded db, and plot those (via whichever means you wish).

Comment: Can you please illustrate with an example wherein I don't need to sample again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply on using plot function, I also wanted to use logp without sampling again so that I get the log probability of the posterior for comparison.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. The backend only saves the sampled value, not its associated log-probability value. The only way you could do something like that is if you created a deterministic node in your model that returned log-probabilities; then it would be saved as a value in a trace.